# Creating Directories using ghc::filesystem need write permission

Tags: c++, ghc

Am using ghc::filesystem for file i/o. First I create directory tree using
`ghc::filesystem::create_directories` and then use file operations to write data.
The problem am facing is that the directories created using `ghc` deny write permission(hence I need to use sudo to delete the folders or files in the folders)
How can I create directory trees without this issue?